# GraphQL Query merge

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

parent container component query

```js
query Product($channelProductNo: Int!, $brandUrl: String!) {
  channelProduct(channelProductNo: $channelProductNo) {
    productImages {
      url
      imageType
      width
      height
    }
  }
  gnbWidget(brandUrl: $brandUrl) {
    ...commonWidgetField
    ... on GnbWidget {
      gnbType
      nameType

      logo {
        ...imageField
      }
      expansionTypeLogo {
        ...imageField
      }
      textColor
    }
    isCorvered
  }
}
```

child component query

```js
query LikedProduct($channelProductNo: Int!) {
  channelProduct(channelProductNo: $channelProductNo) {
    productImages {
      url
      imageType
      width
      height
    }
  }
}
```

The channel Product of the Product query, It is the same as the channel product of the Liked Product query.

The product query depends on the channel product query.

If I modify the LikedProduct query, I want to use the Product query to be modified the same.

like this

```js
query ChannelProduct($channelProductNo: Int! $url: String) {
  channelProduct(channelProductNo: $channelProductNo, url:$url) {
    productImages {
      url
    }
  }
}
```

```js
query Product($channelProductNo: Int!, $brandUrl: String!) {
  channelProduct(channelProductNo: $channelProductNo, url: $url) {
    productImages {
      url
    }
  }
  gnbWidget(brandUrl: $brandUrl) {
    ...commonWidgetField
    ... on GnbWidget {
      gnbType
      nameType

      logo {
        ...imageField
      }
      expansionTypeLogo {
        ...imageField
      }
      textColor
    }
    isCorvered
  }
}
```

Is there a way to manage each one at a time without modification?

Comment: Any reason for querying [in child component] the same data as available in parent? Just pass data as props to child?

Comment: to use apollo cache 
This is because props passing becomes more complex as the depth increases.

Comment: You're doing the same passing down ulr/id needed to query inside childs - how it differs to pass complex data? Separate main query, define them externally ("*.graphql" files) - use the same query copy in parent/childs - with **fetch policy cache only** inside children. This can be better than overfetching - querying more fields in parent, less in child.